# Selection sorting with an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, selection-sort

I need help sorting an integer array using selection sort. It won't sort for some reaons. Below is my demo/main.

```
  02 
  20 
  01
```

it should be

```
  01 
  02 
  20
```

My demo/main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    SelectionSortArray[] ints = new SelectionSortArray[3];

    ints [0] = new SelectionSortArray(02);
    ints [1] = new SelectionSortArray(20);
    ints [2] = new SelectionSortArray(01);

    System.out.println("Unsorted array: ");

    for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(ints[index]);
    }


    SelectionSort.selectionSort(ints);

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Sorted array using selection sort: ");

    for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(ints[index]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why you are not using `Collections.sort()` method?

Comment: @Sanbhat it's probably homework, so collections.sort is probably out of the question

Comment: @sanbhat I need to sort the integer array using the SelectionSort class/method.

Comment: @sanbhat because `Collections.sort()` doesn't work with Arrays . @user2256002  see `Arrays.sort()` when you have spare time to get to know other way to efficiently sort (with 1.7 it uses `DualPivotQuicksort` internally )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing and debugging a specific fragment of code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `compareTo` method in the `SelectionSortArray` class is incorrect.  The [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method must return an `int` less than zero if the current object is less than the other object, yet you have it returning `1`.

Quoting from the linked Javadocs:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Try these changes:

```
if (num == other.num) {
    result = 0;   // This was correct; no change here.
} else if (num < other.num) {
    result = -1;  // Changed from 1 to -1.
} else {
    result = 1;   // 1 or 2 is fine, as long as it's positive
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CompareTo function is wrong. Just change it to:

```
public int compareTo(SelectionSortArray other) {
    return num.compareTo(other.num);     
}
```

The key is the -1 / 0 / 1 return codes, rather than the "0,1,2" that you're using.

Generally if you're comparing built in types, it's easier to just delegate to the built in comparison operators.

Note: To use "num.compareTo" you need to use "Integer" rather than "int". If you want to stick with "int", you need the solution posted by rgettman.

Answer (score 0):

Note that along with the changes to `compareTo`,

```
return Integer.compare(this.num,other.num)
```

Which is implemented to return what you are returning but in a concise way

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

if you want to see the printed output in the way you listed in your question use

```
System.out.format("%02d%n",ints[index].num);
```

or alter `toString()` to `return String.format("%02d",num)`

You might also want to see `java.util.Arrays` source code so see how few other similar methods have been implemented. Also consider changing your class name to indicate that it holds number `CustomNumber` and encapsulate your class to avoid direct access to `num`.

And another Interesting catch in your code

```
    SelectionSortArray[] ints = new SelectionSortArray[8];
    ints[0] = new SelectionSortArray(01);
    ints[1] = new SelectionSortArray(02);
    ints[3] = new SelectionSortArray(03);
    ints[4] = new SelectionSortArray(04);
    ints[5] = new SelectionSortArray(05);
    ints[6] = new SelectionSortArray(06);
    ints[7] = new SelectionSortArray(07);
    ints[8] = new SelectionSortArray(08);//???
```

if you precede a number with `0` it will be an Octal number and allowed digits are 0 - 7 hence you will see compilation error above. Also

```
    System.out.println(0123);
    System.out.println(0234);
```

will not print

```
0123
0234
```

as you (un)expected !

```
83
156
```

Just be cautious while using octal numbers in your code.